# Does Sartre ever talk about irrelevance?

Tags: society, sartre, practical-ethics, authenticity

Does Sartre ever talk about authenticity in terms of *irrelevance*?

I think that authenticity means (amongst other things) both being irrelevant and failing to act: that membership of a group which cannot achieve its goals despite having (relevance) the opportunity to, is less authentic than membership of a group which never has the opportunity to achieve its goals (irrelevance).

Does Sartre have an answer to this formula, and what is it?

Comment: More importantly, does Sartre ever talk about authenticity with respect to groups of people rather than individuals.

Comment: @virmaior i did the obvious edit, though it reads less like a good question now

Comment: *Authenticity* is a concept I associate with Sartre; but does he actually mention *irrelevance*?

Comment: that's what i was asking :) !

Comment: This could definitely be developed a little more -- what about Sartre's notion of authenticity makes you think he *could* be receptive to such an interpretation as you seem to suggest here? The suggestion itself is already a bit leading (maybe some of it could be moved to an answer?)

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at. I ask you though. Is irrelevance the same thing as never having had the opportunity to achieve one's goals? But never mind about that, I see how you connect the two concepts. To be honest I don't know how Sartre treated authenticity but isn't authenticity to do with how your actions and claims align? What I am saying is, wouldn't it matter if the group claimed they could achieve their goals (or not achieve as the case may be). Wouldn't that idea need to be part of your explanation? Yours is a very specific question, what motivates the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think that he doesn't talk about this separate from the overall sense of inauthenticity.  Irrelevance is the inauthentic assumption that a choice would not have any effect, before making the choice and finding out, or even really playing it out in one's head.  It is a basic lie that evades freedom, and it does not need separate discussion.

The 'protagonist' in *Nausea*, for instance, obviously continually rejects possible actions as 'irrelevant'.  He may not put it that way, over and over again, but that is a lot of his internal reasoning.  Meanwhile his continual undercutting of his ability to choose is not rational, and it is destroying him.  If he took some of those irrelevant actions, his ability to abide the remainder of humanity might improve.

Comment: marx *apparently* tried to demarcate himself from the pseudo / failed revolutionaries of the revolution via 'principles'.

Comment: @idiotan Is this comment in the right place?  The question and the answer are about Sartre, I don't get the connection.

Comment: The problem was you have to have an ethics to judge this kind of thing. In his very late interview with Benny Levy,  Sartre hoped to develop an ethics for the Left. I think this had bothered him for years.   He knew it was a problem in Being & Nothingness.

Comment: @Gordon  How does this in particular call for an ethical consideration?  Inauthenticity causes this character a specific sort of avoidable pain.  He would be well advised to be rid of that pain, without any need for a moral framing.  I agree that is not  the best reason to be authentic, but I don't think Existentialism is about the best of anything, just what is really going on.

Comment: Right. If existentialism is not about the best of anything then Sartre was not justified in even bringing up inauthenticity in B&N. Sartre and others later realized the "mistake". But Sartre wanted to retain the concept!  So he wanted an ethics. (Now Nausea, I thought the character ended the book on an authentic note, though it has been a while since I've read it.)

Comment: So at least to Sartre (deep down), it not just any choice, or any commitment. So it's being true to the self but not true to perhaps a deluded self, true in a social sense in that others would agree that it is a choice true to the self.  The waiter in B&N is being judged by Sartre, so you see it's not just up to the waiter. So this was a problem with the book. Sartre rushed the book. He wanted a hit, a serious book, but problems with the book dogged him from then on.  He needed to spend more time thinking it through, but he published.  This is my understanding.